# assert numpy dtype to be any kind of integer

Tags: python, numpy, dtype

I have a function that accepts numpy arrays of integer types, i.e., `int32`, `uint8`, `>i4` etc. Right now I have something like

```py
def myfun(a):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    assert a.dtype in [
        "int8", "int16", "int32", "int64",
        "uint8", "uint16", "uint32", "uint64",
        ">i1", ">i2",
        # ...
    ]
```

and I'm not sure if I missed anything. Is there a NumPy function that can do this for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use [`np.issubdtype`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.issubdtype.html) of [`np.integer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html):

```
dtypes = np.int64, np.float64, np.uint8, '>i2'

for dtype in dtypes:
    print(f"{dtype} is integer? {np.issubdtype(dtype, np.integer)}")
# <class 'numpy.int64'> is integer? True
# <class 'numpy.float64'> is integer? False
# <class 'numpy.uint8'> is integer? True
# >i2 is integer? True
```

Answer (score 0):

I found looking around the following documentation describing the type hierarchy in numpy. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html

```
a = np.array([1,2]).astype(">i2")
if issubclass(a.dtype.type, np.integer):
     print("Type is an integer!")
```

Comment: This will break if the dtype is `int64` or `uint64`

Comment: @DeepSpace. How so? I've just tested it and from a cursory glance it looks like it is working.

Comment: `assert np.array([1, 2], dtype=np.int64).dtype in [np.integer]` causes an `AssertionError` and a deprecation warning. I believe OP wants this assertion to pass

Comment: @DeepSpace. Your snippet is not working but my code is checking if the type of the dtype is a subclass. I edited the code to eliminate the silly requirement of getting an element via indexing.

Comment: You also changed `isinstance` to `issubclass` which I believe is the key here. Good.

Comment: this is similar to the implementation of `np.issubdtype`. see https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.20.0/numpy/core/numerictypes.py#L359-L423